# How to create sharp 1px lines un UWP?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, uwp-xaml

I just found out that uwp cant draw sharp "Black" lines made up of 1px.
This is my XAML code:

```
<Line X1="0" X2="100" Y1="10" Y2="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />
```

The attribute SnapsToDevicePixels doesnt seem to exist in uwp so im kind of desperate here. I also tried setting the stroke thickness to 0.5 or 1.5 which doesnt make a different. The line is grey instead of black. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `<Line X1="0.5" X2="100.5" Y1="10.5" Y2="10.5" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" />`

Comment: Have you tried setting `UseLayoutRounding` to `False`?

Comment: You don't want to use StrokeThickness for this. Try creating a 1px high rectangle instead and set it's fill to black.